# Visual C++ Runtime Package to metro style

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8

how can i add Visual C++ Runtime Package to metro style C# app in windows 8? Adding this shows error in project.

Answer (score 1):

In the Add Reference dialog choose the Windows\Extensions view you will see Visual C++ Runtime Package

Answer (score 0):

See this blog post for more details about C++ Runtime package:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/09/28/10354327.aspx